# How to run asp.net in ubuntu using apache

Tags: apache2

My office server run on Windows 2008 server and I want to shift to ubuntu Server but the problem is that all my application are based on asp using dot net framework 4.0, so how do I configure to run in ubuntu. I have heard about apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using Mono.

> Mono is a software platform designed to allow developers to easily
>   create cross platform applications. Sponsored by Xamarin, Mono is an
>   open source implementation of Microsoft's .NET Framework based on the
>   ECMA standards for C# and the Common Language Runtime. A growing
>   family of solutions and an active and enthusiastic contributing
>   community is helping position Mono to become the leading choice for
>   development of Linux applications.<sup>1</sup>

[Download](http://mono-project.com/DistroPackages/Ubuntu) Mono for Ubuntu

Also take a look at ModMono.

> ModMono is an Apache module which provides ASP.NET support for Apache
>   web server. We will be using Apache as an alternative for Microsoft’s
>   IIS in Windows.<sup>2</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)</sup>

<sup><sup>**2**</sup>Source:[Running ASP.NET applications in Ubuntu using ModMono](http://ubuntuexperiment.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/running-aspnet-applications-in-ubuntu-using-modmono/)</sup>